Pass script with SNMPD server returns duplicate OID
I have this snmpd.conf that uses a pass script for retrieving custom information:
root@srvweb:~# cat /etc/snmp/snmpd.conf
...
pass .1.3.6.1.2.1.1.9.1.5.0  /etc/snmp/users.sh

Contents of this script and execution output are:
root@srvweb:~# cat /etc/snmp/users.sh
#!/bin/bash
OID=".1.3.6.1.2.1.1.9.1.5.0"
TYPE="string"
USERS=$(who --count | head -1 | sed 's/^.*://')
UNIQUE_USERS=$(echo "$USERS" | tr ' ' '\n' | sort -u | tr '\n' ' ')
echo -en "${OID}\r\n"
echo -en "${TYPE}\r\n"
echo -en "${UNIQUE_USERS} \r\n"
exit 0
root@srvweb:~# /etc/snmp/users.sh
.1.3.6.1.2.1.1.9.1.5.0
string
test

But if i run snmpwalk -v2c -c public localhost it reports a duplicated OID:
iso.3.6.1.2.1.1.9.1.5.0 = STRING: "test "
iso.3.6.1.2.1.1.9.1.5.0 = STRING: "test "


Error: OID not increasing: iso.3.6.1.2.1.1.9.1.5.0

>= iso.3.6.1.2.1.1.9.1.5.0

Any ideas why iso.3.6.1.2.1.1.9.1.5.0 output is duplicated?
I've tried changing echo output without forcing \\r\\n output without success, so I'm kind of stuck on this.

Not on-point for your question, but some general notes: Stay away from all-caps variable names (which are in the namespace for variables meaningful to the shell and operating system), and printf '%s\r\n' "$oid" "$type" "$unique_users" would be both safer and more reliable than the three echo -en statements -- unlike echo -e or echo -n, the printf version works the same way on all POSIX-compliant shells; see Why is printf better than echo? on [unix.se].

(yes, the linked naming guidelines are for environment variables, but setting a regular shell variable overwrites any like-named environment variable, so the convention necessarily applies to both).

...beyond that, I'd use set -x within the script, or bash -x yourscript when invoking it, to trace what's going wrong a line at a time so you can ask a question that's more narrowly focused on exactly what first went wrong and why/how.
